# Wordpress - referencing get_post_meta inside & outside of the loop properly?

Tags: wordpress

I've successfully created my post meta boxes, saved the data and I understand how to retrieve the data. Within the custom meta boxes I have a field for the page branding that will decide what color scheme per the product line we are featuring on that page.

I have a class per the color scheme that is triggered when the body has a class of the product line name appended to it. For example:

```
<body class="product-drinks">
```

OR

```
<body class="product-abcwidgets">
```

Depending on what product line is selected in the meta box for that post will determine what style sheet will be included.

For example if I chose "product-drinks" then the stylesheet included would be **product-drinks.css**.

Most of the meta box data I need to use within the loop but I also need to access the page branding mega field data outside of the loop. How would I grab this data if I need it outside of the loop?

I initially thought of placing some of the data in an array while in the loop as such and then referencing the $page_options array value in the body tag as such:

(outside of the loop in the header)

```
<body class="<?php echo $page_options['pageBranding'];?>
```

from within the loop"

```
$page_options = array(  

        'pageBranding'  =>  get_post_meta($post_id, 'pageBranding', true), 
        'layout'        =>  get_post_meta($post_id, 'pageLayout', true)
);
```

Am I doing this correctly or is there a better way of doing this? Or should I only reference the meta fields I need within the loop and then use **global $wp_query;** outside of the loop and get the post meta that way for the data I need for the body and stylesheets?

Answer (score 1):

If you need the data outside the loop, I'd suggest using $wp_query or global $post.

```
<?php global $post; ?>
```

Then you can call it just as normal

```
<?php $samplemeta = get_post_meta($post->ID, "your_meta_name", true); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I figured this out a while back, but it's always great to have someone confirm what you are doing. Thank you Joe!